# Port Forwarding Huawei HG8247H for BTC node

Tags: port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, bitcoin, bitcoind

Hi I am trying to set up a full Bitcoin node to support the network, but I can't seem to get the port forwarding for port 8333 right on this Huawei router. I have attached screenshot of the port mapping page of my router. If anyone can tell me exactly what to put where, I'd be very much obliged.

PS I already have a static IP.

[image: [Port Mapping attachment [1]]]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the external port number as well. I've never seen the external source IP address/port number setting before but chances are its not critical.

Port numbers need not to be from the external port number to internal port number.

Comment: So I only need to fill in External port number with 8333--8333? Thanks

Comment: When I use nmap to see if port is open, I get OPEN when I use the local IP, but "Host seems down" for the public IP. I don't get it. Anyone have a suggestion?